# Python error; graph hangs;Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

1. I am trying to plot two graph in Tkinter canvas.
2. Problem is after few plots of data, graph gets hanged.
   It takes up huge resources of window, then i have to kill it forcefully.
3. Since I have to plot the graph continuously like that in CRO/DSO so I have to go line by line rather than using any library. Didn't find any lib where graph is printed continuously.
4. I am using python 2.7 on window 8 64 bit.
5. But in the end I have to shift the code to Raspberry pi board.

code:
        from Tkinter import *
        import Tkinter
        import time
        from random import randint
        import math

```
    #global vars
    hor_pixel = 5                      #starting point of horizontal pixel
    old_ver_pixel_1 = 0                #last pixel value of graph 1
    old_ver_pixel_2 = 0                #last pixel value of graph 2
    new_ver_pixel_1 = 0                #new pixel value of graph 1
    new_ver_pixel_2 = 0                #new pixel value of graph 2
    y0_1 = 0                           # y cordinate of graph 1 & 2
    y1_1 = 0
    y0_2 = 0
    y1_2 = 0

    def pixel(C):
        global hor_pixel
        global old_ver_pixel_1
        global old_ver_pixel_2    
        global new_ver_pixel_1
        global new_ver_pixel_2
        global y0_1
        global y1_1
        global y0_2
        global y1_2    

        if(new_ver_pixel_1 == old_ver_pixel_1):
            new_ver_pixel_1 = new_ver_pixel_1 + 1
        if(new_ver_pixel_2 == old_ver_pixel_2):
            new_ver_pixel_2 = new_ver_pixel_2 + 1            

        if(new_ver_pixel_1 > old_ver_pixel_1):
            y0_1 = old_ver_pixel_1
            y1_1 = new_ver_pixel_1
        else:
            y0_2 = old_ver_pixel_2
            y1_2 = new_ver_pixel_2        

        coord = hor_pixel, y0_1, hor_pixel, y1_1
        coord2 = hor_pixel, y0_2, hor_pixel, y1_2        
        hor_pixel = hor_pixel + 1

        if(hor_pixel > 400):
            hor_pixel = 5;

        old_ver_pixel_1 = new_ver_pixel_1
        old_ver_pixel_2 = new_ver_pixel_2

        C.create_line(hor_pixel , 0 , hor_pixel , 500, fill = 'black')
        C.create_line(coord, fill = 'red')
        C.create_line(coord2, fill = 'yellow')
        C.pack()
        #print(new_ver_pixel_1 , new_ver_pixel_2)



    def graph():
        global new_ver_pixel_1
        global new_ver_pixel_2

        screen = Tkinter.Tk()
        screen.title("Analog Channel")
        screen.geometry("800x800")
        C = Tkinter.Canvas(screen , bg = "black" , height = 800, width = 800)
        C.pack()

        while True:
            var = 0
            var = var + 1
            new_ver_pixel_1 = randint(0,200) + 200;
            new_ver_pixel_2 = randint(0,200) + 400;
            #print(new_ver_pixel_1 , new_ver_pixel_2)
            #pixel(C)
            screen.after(100,pixel(C))
            screen.update_idletasks()

        screen.mainloop()


    graph()
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement doesn't do what you think it does:

```
screen.after(100,pixel(C))
```

What you think it does is runs `pixel(C)` every 100ms, but what it actually does is run `pixel(C)` *immediately*, and then schedules `None` to execute in 100ms. This is likely why it is chewing up all your CPU and eventually hanging.

One fix is to change it to `screen.after(100, pixel, C)`. **However**, a custom infinite loop is the wrong way to run a function every 100ms with Tkinter.

What you need to do instead is remove your infinite loop, and leverage the existing infinite loop (`mainloop()`). Move the body of your while loop to a function, and have that function put another call to itself on the event queue using `after`. It will do work, then schedule itself to run again in 100 ms, forever. You can put a check on a global flag if you want to be able to pause or cancel the redrawing.

It looks something like this:

```
def updateGraph(canvas):
    <do the work up updating the graph>
    canvas.after(100, updateGraph, canvas)
```

Comment: `screen.after(100,(lambda :pixel(C)))`

Comment: @SDilmac: I don't know what the point of your comment is. Yes, you can do it that way, but the way I wrote works, too.

Comment: Update with argument(s)
`canvas.after(100, updateGraph, canvas)` only function , not allowed with arguments

Comment: @SDilmac: you are incorrect. `after` absolutely _does_ accept extra arguments.